Why is there a diagonal gray line showing in a PDF converted from MS Word and how can I get rid of it?
I'm getting a strange irregular, diagonal, gray line across a single page of PDF documents I'm creating from MS Word (it's a 3-page document, but the line only appears on one page). It looks a bit like a shadow of a gray line that wasn't erased properly.
I get it when I use "Save As" a PDF, and I also get it when I print to a PDF from a PDF program, such as PDF24. I have tried turning off all reviewing/tracking functions in Word.
I'm a new user and the webpage won't let me paste an image, but the link below takes you to a cropped screenshot of what the gray line looks like. Any suggestions would be appreciated.




Yes, it is exactly where a watermark would be. I never put a watermark on the document, but I went to the Design tab and clicked on "Remove Watermark," just in case, but it didn't help.
